# How do I set the position a camera in three.js without it rotating?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an interface I developed with three.js using the CSS3DObject rendering tool.
I have set the orbit to 0 to prevent rotating and limit my movement to panning and zooming.

Please note I'm also using Orbit Control.

I set the position of the camera to x=-2000 with the following code:

```
camera.position.x=-2000;
camera.position.z=4000;
```

When I do this, the camera moves positions but is still pointing to (0,0,0) resulting in a skewed look.
So I assume that I need to give it a vector

```
camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);  //keeps the camera horizontal
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(2000,0,0));  //should point the camera straight forward
```

Please note that I'm still trying to find a good explanation of how setting up the lookAt works.

Answer (score 5):

After a bit more research, it seems that the orbit control is overriding the camera.lookAt and as a result, doesn't do anything.
To achieve the panning I set the location of the camera x position equal to the value of the target.
I also removed the camera.up line.

```
var myCameraX = -2000;
var myCameraY = 500;

camera.position.x=myCameraX;
camera.position.y=myCamerYa;
control.target.set(myCameraX,myCameraY,0);
```

Hope that helps someone.